# How to validate SecureConversationToken in a Webservice against a third party secure token service with java ee in wildfly?

Tags: java, wildfly, ws-security, jaas

I have a webservice provider in wildfly 12. I want to secure it with an existing secure token service.

The caller calls the token service and puts the received token in the request header. My Webservice needs to custom validate the token against the existing secure token service and to set the user principle.

My Webservice:

```
@WebServiceProvider(
        wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/MyService.wsdl",
        portName = "MyService",
        serviceName = "MyService",
        targetNamespace = "http://www.MyService.net/namespace")
@WebServlet(
        urlPatterns = "/myservcies/MyService")
@ServiceMode(value = Service.Mode.MESSAGE)

public class MyService implements Provider<Source> {

    @Override
    public Source invoke(Source request) {
    //business logic
    }

}
```

The WSDL

```
...
 <wsp:Policy xmlns:wssp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702"
                wsu:Id="AuthSecurityPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>

            <wssp:TransportBinding>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <wssp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <wssp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </wssp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256 />
                            <sp:InclusiveC14N/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </wssp:TransportBinding>

            <wssp:SupportingTokens>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:SecureConversationToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wssp:Issuer>
                            <wsa:Address>http://my/SecurityTokenService</wsa:Address>
                        </wssp:Issuer>
                    </sp:SecureConversationToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </wssp:SupportingTokens>        
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
...
```

Request header:

```
...
<soapenv:Header>

        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsc="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">

            <wsc:SecurityContextToken>

                <wsc:Identifier>uuid_example</wsc:Identifier>

            </wsc:SecurityContextToken>

        </wsse:Security>

    </soapenv:Header>
...
```

The wildfly logs show the following message:

```
WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-1) Interceptor for {http://www.MyService.net/namespace}MyService#{http://www.MyService.net/namespace}getData has thrown exception, unwinding now: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.tokenstore.MemoryTokenStore.getToken(MemoryTokenStore.java:79)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.TokenStoreCallbackHandler.handle(TokenStoreCallbackHandler.java:49)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.SecurityContextTokenProcessor.getSecret(SecurityContextTokenProcessor.java:109)
    ....
```

**Update:**

Look @ Federico Sierra comment for the original answer.

I decided against implementing a custom token store. Because my deployment would need additional cxf libaries. It also could break if I update wildfly. Maybe I can move the tokenvalidation in a separate login modul? I do only know login modules which handle username/password and certificates, but not custom token in the request header.

Comment: Take a look: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html specially in WS-Security Configuration parameter `org.apache.cxf.ws.security.tokenstore.TokenStore`

Comment: That did work. But then I have to include cxf dependencies in my war file. I descided to change my approch: limit my war file to only java ee and try to build a login modul (?) for wildfly. So I do not have to change my service if I upgrade wildfly. Will update my question.